# How to achieve automatic login to meteor server using ddp?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, ddp

I am using asteroid npm package in my chrome extension to connect to meteor app(which uses account-password meteor package).I can log in to back end with login mixin but how do I check if there is a logged in session already present?